# Showing more card using slice() JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a section where I'm pulling blog posts and showcasing them all. By default, 13 `.resourceCard`'s are show and then when clicking load more, 9 more should show.

However, when clicking the load more button, it only showcases the next 9, but not anything after that on subsequent click (doens't show cards 23+).

Using `hiddenCard.slice(x, 9)` doesn't work either as only the console log appears.

Where is my logic falling apart?

### Demo

```js
$(function () {

  var loadmoreBtn = $('.resourceListing__loadmore');
  var hiddenCard = $('.insertCard:hidden');
  var x = 13;

  loadmoreBtn.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x = x + 9;
    console.log("click");
    hiddenCard.slice(0, 9).fadeIn().addClass("insertCard--flex");
    if(hiddenCard.length == 0){
      loadmoreBtn.hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --navy: #0E185F;
}

.placeholderCard,
.resourceCard {
  padding: 60px;
  border: 1px solid var(--black);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.placeholderCard {
  background: var(--navy);
  color: var(--white);
  padding: 20px;
}

.resourceListing {
  padding: 80px 0;
}
.resourceListing__loadmore {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 60px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.resourceListing .insertCard:nth-child(n+16) {
  display: none;
}

.insertCard {
  display: flex;
}
.insertCard--flex {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<main class="resourceListing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row resourceListing__posts">

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 2</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="placeholderCard">This card is not part of the slice</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 3</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 4</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="placeholderCard">This card is not part of the slice</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 5</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 6</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 7</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 8</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 9</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 10</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 11</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 12</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 13</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 14</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 15</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 16</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 17</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 18</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 19</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 20</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 21</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 22</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 23</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 24</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 25</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <a class="resourceListing__loadmore">Load more</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you get list of hidden cards once. Then process 9 items from that list without updating the list. So next time it processes the same 9 cards again.

To fix that you need update the list with:

```
hiddenCard = hiddenCard.slice(9);
```

```js
$(function () {

  var loadmoreBtn = $('.resourceListing__loadmore');
  var hiddenCard = $('.insertCard:hidden');
  var x = 13;

  loadmoreBtn.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x = x + 9;
    console.log("click", hiddenCard.length);
    hiddenCard.slice(0, 9).fadeIn().addClass("insertCard--flex")
    //update the list
    hiddenCard = hiddenCard.slice(9);
    if(hiddenCard.length == 0){
      loadmoreBtn.hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --navy: #0E185F;
}

.placeholderCard,
.resourceCard {
  padding: 60px;
  border: 1px solid var(--black);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.placeholderCard {
  background: var(--navy);
  color: var(--white);
  padding: 20px;
}

.resourceListing {
  padding: 80px 0;
}
.resourceListing__loadmore {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 60px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.resourceListing .insertCard:nth-child(n+16) {
  display: none;
}

.insertCard {
  display: flex;
}
.insertCard--flex {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<main class="resourceListing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row resourceListing__posts">

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 2</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="placeholderCard">This card is not part of the slice</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 3</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 4</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="placeholderCard">This card is not part of the slice</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 5</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 6</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 7</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 8</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 9</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 10</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 11</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 12</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 13</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 14</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 15</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 16</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 17</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 18</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 19</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 20</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 21</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 22</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 23</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 24</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 25</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <a class="resourceListing__loadmore">Load more</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

Alternatively, you could move `var hiddenCard = $('.insertCard:hidden');` into `click` function

P.S.
You should use `const` and `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 1):

You can start by removing this line:

```js
var x = 13;
```

because no need a counter! And then move this line:

```js
var hiddenCard = $('.insertCard:hidden');
```

to beginning of `click` event after:

```js
e.preventDefault();
```

Now with this changes, every time you click on **Load More** button, you create a new collection of remaining hidden cards and then make a slice of first 9 hidden cards.

Accourding to the jQuery documents:

> ..., the .slice() method constructs a *new jQuery object* containing a subset of the elements specified by the start and, optionally, end argument.

---

### Update

After all these changes, to hide the **Load Mode** button, you need to update your `if` statement to something like this:

```js
if(hiddenCard.slice(9).length == 0){
    loadmoreBtn.hide();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Although this will solve the main issue, however it will have a side issue, where "load more" will not hide when there are no more cards available until next click.

Comment: Yes. I forget about that. but it could be happen by a small change in code:
Just change the `if(hiddenCard.length == 0){` to `if(hiddenCard.slice(9).length == 0){` and done.

Answer (score 0):

After making a [codepen](https://codepen.io/JJStanton/pen/bGvPPzN) of your code, I noticed you are not updating your 'hiddenCard' array after loading more. If you simply update the array, you code will work.

```js
$(function () {
  var loadmoreBtn = $('.resourceListing__loadmore');
  var x = 13;

  loadmoreBtn.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x = x + 9;
   var hiddenCard = $('.insertCard:hidden');
   hiddenCard.slice(0, 9).fadeIn().addClass("insertCard--flex");
   hiddenCard = $('.insertCard:hidden');

   if(!hiddenCard.length){
     loadmoreBtn.hide();
   }
  });

});
```

```css
:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --navy: #0E185F;
}

.placeholderCard,
.resourceCard {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid var(--black);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.placeholderCard {
  background: var(--navy);
  color: var(--white);
  padding: 20px;
}

.resourceListing {
  padding: 80px 0;
}
.resourceListing__loadmore {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 60px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.resourceListing .insertCard:nth-child(n+16) {
  display: none;
}

.insertCard {
  display: flex;
}
.insertCard--flex {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<main class="resourceListing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row resourceListing__posts">

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 2</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="placeholderCard">This card is not part of the slice</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 3</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 4</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="placeholderCard">This card is not part of the slice</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 5</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 6</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 7</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 8</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 9</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 10</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 11</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 12</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 13</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 14</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 15</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 16</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 17</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 18</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 19</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 20</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 21</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 22</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 23</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 24</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 insertCard">
        <div class="resourceCard">Card 25</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <a class="resourceListing__loadmore">Load more</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: FYI the declaration of the `hiddenCard` outside of click function in this case is redundant. And also, it doesn't hide "load more" when there are no more cards until next click.

Comment: @vanowm true that. Will refactor the example. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head><title></title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
   <style>
   :root {
      --black: #000000;
      --white: #FFFFFF;
      --navy: #0E185F;
    }

    .placeholderCard,
    .resourceCard {
      padding: 30px;
      border: 1px solid var(--black);
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .placeholderCard {
      background: var(--navy);
      color: var(--white);
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .resourceListing {
      padding: 80px 0;
    }
    .resourceListing__loadmore {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 60px 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .resourceListing .insertCard:nth-child(n+10) {
      display: none;
    }

    .insertCard {
      display: flex;
    }
    .insertCard--flex {
        display: flex !important;
    }
   </style>
   </head>
  <body>
    <main class="resourceListing">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row resourceListing__posts">

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 1</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 2</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="placeholderCard">Card 3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 4</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 5</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="placeholderCard">Card 6</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 7</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 8</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 9</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 10</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 11</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 12</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 13</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 14</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 15</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 16</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 17</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 18</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 19</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 20</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 21</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 21</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 22</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 23</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 24</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 25</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4 insertCard">
            <div class="resourceCard">Card 26</div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <a class="resourceListing__loadmore">Load more</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </main>
    <script>
    var x = 9;
    $('.resourceListing__loadmore').on('click', function(event){
       x = x + 9;
       $('.insertCard:hidden').slice(0, 9).addClass("insertCard--flex").show();
       if(!$('.insertCard:hidden').length){
         $('.resourceListing__loadmore').hide();
       }
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```